# A few questions regarding GLSL pipeline

Tags: opengl, glsl, openframeworks

I used to code HLSL when I was working with DirectX but have forgotten quite a lot and I am now trying to figure out GLSL and how it works.  I am using a fixed pipeline of OpenGL in OpenFramework which is sort of a new concept to me but a good starting point.

My first question:  For the Vertex Shader all vertices will be computed before entering the Fragment Shader, correct?  So I can preccompute information here like finding the Min/Max values of the Z pos of all vertices feeded into the frame buffer?

Then when entering the Fragment Shader I can access these precomputed values by the varying variables?  So if I set a value from the Vertex Shader in a varying variable (like Min/Max from a z position of a vertex) I can later access these set values from the Fragment Shader?

Also the build-in variable gl_FragCoord when accessing the Z element always seem to yield a 1.0 for every vertex for me.  Is this related to how I transform the vertices' position in the Vertex Shader?

And finally I am trying to find the Min/Max Z position of all the vertices and pass them along to the Fragment Shader, is the follow code correct?

```
varying float minZ = 9999.9;
varying float maxZ = -9999.9;

void main()
{
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    gl_TexCoord[1] = gl_MultiTexCoord1;
    gl_FrontColor  = gl_Color;
    gl_Position    = ftransform();

    if (gl_Position.z < minZ) minZ = gl_Position.z;
    if (gl_Position.z > maxZ) maxZ = gl_Position.z;
}
```

Sorry if this is an inappropriate way of asking questions on StackOverflow, perhaps I should've split it up into several questions.

Comment: The vertices for a primitive is at lest calculated before the fragment shader runs for that primitive.

Comment: I would recommend sticking with GL/GLSL 3.2/3+. Then you pass in geometry using generic vertex attributes (Using VAOs). No hidden magical stuff going on. Simple and clean. All uniforms also has be be passed manually, so the magical `ftransform` dies as well.

Comment: Yeah I find the fixed pipeline a bit strange as I am not entirely sure what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For the Vertex Shader all vertices will be computed before entering the Fragment Shader, correct?

No.

> So I can preccompute information here like finding the Min/Max values of the Z pos of all vertices feeded into the frame buffer?

Not directly, because the vertex shader sees one vertex at a time and GPUs operate in parallel. Determining min/max would require something like map-reduce to be efficient, which requires some way to pass information between thread. It could be done, but not very efficiently.

In your code snippet `minZ` and `maxZ` are *not* globals shared between all vertices. They are local varyings tied to the vertex currently processed.

> Then when entering the Fragment Shader I can access these precomputed values by the varying variables?

Those are not really "precomputed", they're just processed in the immediate step before. It's not that first the vertex shader is executed for all vertices, then the fragment shader. Each primitive (i.e. a single triangle) passes right through the stages without being stored inbetween.

Comment: Ah thanks!  That sure cleared up a lot.  So to get the max/min of the Z pos of a shape I am drawing I have to find this value on the main program instead (aka the CPU part) and then send in this value as a uniform to the Shader?

Comment: @Placeable: It can be done on the GPU, but the vertex and fragment shader stages are not the right place for this; it can be done using them, but it's very, very cumbersome. Compute shaders are much better suited for this, as they can access the data in the buffers arbitrarily. But compute shaders are available only with OpenGL-4 and later (and require hardware that can cope with them).

Comment: Sadly that is an option not available for me but thanks for the input.  As of now I am looping through all triangles on the CPU and check the 3 vertices Z position, average that, and checks if it above or under the previous min/max values and if so set it.  These values I then send into my shaders as uniform variables.  Not the best solution though.

Comment: @Placeable: What do you need that information for exactly for?

Comment: Well I am trying to add a separate fog effect for each shape I draw.  Just fading each shape's fragment based on how deep they lie.  So for each shapes' vertices I want to find the min/max z-position so I can interpolate the alpha color between these min/max values for the fragments between them.  Erm, makes sense? S: